# Is there a word for “carefully planning your future” or “treading carefully”?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, word-choice, word-usage, synonyms

I want a small word, if possible. Words from other languages or old English will also suffice. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: A sample sentence please.

Comment: You must tread carefully if you want a risk-free life

Answer (score 1):

**Prudent** is explicitly about planning ahead:

[Oxford dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/prudent):

> **prudent** adjective
>
> Acting with or showing care and thought for the future.
>       ‘no prudent money manager would authorize a loan without first knowing its purpose’
>
> Origin
>
> Late Middle English: from Old French, or from Latin prudent-,
>   contraction of provident- ‘foreseeing, attending to’ (see provident).

**Provident** is even more related to acting ahead, but refers less to being careful:

> **provident** adjective
>
> Making or indicative of timely preparation for the future.
>      ‘she had learned to be provident’

**Circumspect** could also do.

Answer (score -1):

**gingerly**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/gingerly)

> adv. With great care or delicacy; cautiously. adj. Cautious; careful:
>   with a gingerly step.

As in:

> You must step gingerly if you want a risk-free life.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I up-voted the answer, but apparently it needs 15 reputation to count as an up-vote